# Restoring database from .mdf and .ldf files of SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-restore

For some reason I have to uninstall SQL Server 2008 R2 but before that I copied two files (`.mdf` and `.ldf`) of my database from

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQL2008\MSSQL\DATA

Now, the question is, is it possible for me to recover the database from these files in my new installed SQL Server 2008 R2.

If yes: then how can I do this?

Comment: Yes, you can [attach a database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx) when you have the two files.

Comment: i tried to do so but it gives an error occurred when attaching the database.

Comment: error saying unable to open the physical file.
operating system error 5(access denied)
MSSQL Server error 5120

Comment: Are the files on the physical machine where SQL Server runs?

Comment: i find this [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9e563890-e35f-4524-82b9-3cca08fec5ed/unable-to-open-physical-file-operating-system-error-5-5error-not-found-microsoft-sql-server)

- right-click on the files(.mdf and .LDF) in Windows Explorer, select Properties
-select the Security tab
-Click Advanced
-Click Change Permission
-Uncheck "Include inheritable permissions",a window will open
-Click Remove(removes all permissions),the window will close
-Click Add
-Enter your login name and click OK, the permission window will open
-Check Full Control-Allow
-Click OK,OK,OK,OK

Comment: Since my user does have permissions, I was able to get around the access denied error by running management studio as administrator.

Comment: you can also restore your database files using SQL Server Management Studio http://www.serverintellect.com/support/sqlserver/sql-database-attach/

Comment: Another possible solution for that, you need to provide full access to the database files. see here: https://mirzahusain.wordpress.com/2017/02/03/sql-server-attach-database-error-5120/

Answer (score 124):

Yes, it is possible.
The steps are:

1. First Put the `.mdf` and `.ldf` file in  `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\` folder
2. Then go to sql software , Right-click “Databases” and click the “Attach” option to open the Attach Databases dialog box
3. Click the “Add” button to open and Locate Database Files  From  `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\`folder
4. Click the "OK" button. SQL Server Management Studio loads the database from the `.MDF` file.

Answer (score 14):

From a script (one that works):

```
CREATE DATABASE Northwind
ON ( FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Northwind.mdf' )
LOG ON ( FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Northwind_log.ldf')
GO
```

obviously update the path:

> `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA`

To where your .mdf and .ldf reside.

Comment: does not work, Msg 5170, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
Cannot create file 'D:\test.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.

Comment: @myro seriously?

Answer (score 13):

First google search yielded me this answer. So I thought of updating this with newer version of attach, detach.

```
Create database dbname 
On 
(   
Filename= 'path where you copied files',   
Filename ='path where you copied log'
)
For attach;
```

Further,if your database is cleanly shutdown(there are no active transactions while database was shutdown) and you dont have log file,you can use below method,SQL server will create a new transaction log file..

```
Create database dbname 
    On 
    (   
    Filename= 'path where you copied files'   
    )
    For attach;
```

if you don't specify transaction log file,SQL will try to look in the default path  and will try to use it irrespective of whether database was cleanly shutdown or not..

Here is what [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms190794.aspx#AttachDb) has to say about this..

> If a read-write database has a single log file and you do not specify a new location for the log file, the attach operation looks in the old location for the file. If it is found, the old log file is used, regardless of whether the database was shut down cleanly. However, if the old log file is not found and if the database was shut down cleanly and has no active log chain, the attach operation attempts to build a new log file for the database.

There are some restrictions with this approach and some side affects too..

> 1.attach-and-detach operations both disable cross-database ownership chaining for the database
>   2.Database trustworthy is set to off
>   3.Detaching a read-only database loses information about the differential bases of differential backups.

Most importantly..you can't attach a database with recent versions to an earlier version

**References:**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms190794.aspx

Answer (score 9):

I have an answer for you
Yes, It is possible.

Go to

SQL Server Management Studio > select Database > click on attach

Then select and add .mdf and .ldf file. Click on OK.

Comment: This didn't work for me, the files have to be in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\`

Answer (score 4):

this is what i did

first execute `create database x`. x is the name of your old database eg the name of the mdf.

Then open sql sever configration and stop the sql sever.

There after browse to the location of your new created database it should be under program file, in my case is

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQL\MSSQL\DATA
```

and repleace the new created mdf and Idf with the old files/database.

then simply restart the sql server and walla :)

Comment: This helped me use the mdf and ldf files to restore the DB. Other methods were giving some kind of error. Thanks Alen!

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you have the .mdf and .ldf files of the database you want to restore. These files contain the data and log information of the database, respectively. Copy them to a location accessible by your SQL Server instance.

Below is the way we can create database using SQLCMD (Command Line):

```
DECLARE @MDFFilePath NVARCHAR(255) = 'C:\Path\To\Your\Database.mdf';
DECLARE @LDFFilePath NVARCHAR(255) = 'C:\Path\To\Your\Database.ldf';

CREATE DATABASE [YourDatabaseName]
ON (FILENAME = @MDFFilePath)
LOG ON (FILENAME = @LDFFilePath)
FOR ATTACH;
```

**Make sure to replace [YourDatabaseName] with the desired database name and provide the correct file paths for your .mdf and .ldf files.**

Another way of doing this is via SSMS.

In SSMS:

- In Object Explorer, right-click on the "Databases" node.
- Choose "Attach..."
- In the "Attach Databases" dialog, click the "Add" button.
- Browse to the location where you copied the .mdf file.
- Select the .mdf file and click "OK."
- You should now see the database listed in the "Databases" folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
use test
go
alter proc restore_mdf_ldf_main (@database varchar(100), @mdf varchar(100),@ldf varchar(100),@filename varchar(200))
as
begin 
begin try
RESTORE DATABASE @database FROM DISK = @FileName
with norecovery,
MOVE @mdf TO 'D:\sql samples\sample.mdf',
MOVE @ldf TO 'D:\sql samples\sample.ldf'
end try
begin catch
SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
print 'Restoring of the database ' + @database + ' failed';
end catch
end

exec restore_mdf_ldf_main product,product,product_log,'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\product.bak'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase 
ON (FILENAME = 'C:\SQLServer\MyDatabase_Data.mdf'), 
(FILENAME = 'C:\SQLServer\ MyDatabase _Log.ldf') 
FOR ATTACH;
```

Comment: Before answering a question, you need to be sure you review the existing answers to ensure your proposal hasn't already been suggested. In this case, [an answer from six years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29053646/3025856) contains the same syntax—but with **significantly** more explanation. In a case like this, the correct course of action is to upvote the existing answer, not repeat the basic syntax as a new answer without _any_ explanation.