# How to reconnect VB Application to the Database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Like a month earlier, I had installed a Forms Over Data (VB2010) application to a user but unfortunately they've lost the computer. Luckily, they had backed up the Data folder with the .MDF and .ldf to a CD. I want to reinstall the app to their new computer. How will I reconnect their database to the new app and enable them to "Resume from where they left"?

Comment: Bah...copying the MDF and LDF files is not a backup solution. They need to be taking proper backups. You can try to attach the mdf file to a sql server. I would strongly recommend immediately taking a backup at that point.

Comment: You need to first figure out which version of Sql Server the user was using on their local machine.  I'll assume this since you say the mdf/ldf were local.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309677/restoring-database-from-mdf-and-ldf-files-of-sql-server-2008 for "attaching" the mdf/ldf.

Comment: @ Sean Which is the most suitable backup so that I advice the other clients with the similar app. Or is it just the normal 'Backup and Restore from Windows?

Comment: @Granada, SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Here are a few articles about backups. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175477.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx. This is NOT a windows backup. You need to use database backups going forward.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find (or install) Sql Server 2008 on the client machine.  We'll call this MySqlServer\MyInstanceName.
2. Attempt to "attach" the mdf/ldf to MySqlServer\MyInstanceName.  Cross your fingers and hope for the best.   We'll say you restored it as MyDataBaseName.
3. If that works...then...  You now have a db that "exists".
4. Hopefully, the devs put the connection string in a .config file.  Do a search in the directory where the application is deployed.  Search for *.config
5. Change the connection-string to reflect MySqlServer\MyInstanceName and MyDataBaseName.    You can look at the URL below for permutations.

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/