# C#/SQL : backup and restore by copy and replace database files?

Tags: c#, sql-server, backup, restore

**First of all, this is a some kind of share knowledge NOT a question.**

I have faced some problems with creating backup and restore of database by the default method of using backup and restore commands **so** i have developed my own one by coping the database files and get them back when needed.

**I will share it in answer to help others.**

Comment: What exactly is it that you are asking / require help with?

Comment: If you want to share some knowledge then post a question and answer it with yourself and accept it.

Comment: it's a kind of share some knowledge, i have edited the question, dividing it into question and answer. thanks.

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If yes: please add `sql-server` tag to make this clear. If not: **what** database system is this for?

Comment: yes, i mean sql server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restoring database from .mdf and .ldf files of SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309677/restoring-database-from-mdf-and-ldf-files-of-sql-server-2008)

Comment: This way has multiple limitations, including: 1)only full backups possible 2)DB goes offline for the duration of backup which leads to all sorts of app errors and user frustration 3)not compatible between mssql versions 4)depending on mssql version, you can have trouble determining location of DB files in a manageable way (i.e. without hardcoding it) 5)unsupported by existing backup solutions (scheduling, backup image management etc). You should rather resolve your backup problems (e.g. ask a question about them here) and not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: i tried to fins solution for my backup errors but i didn't find any answer works with me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution :

First of all you have to know that before any copy or replace database files, you have to set the database in offline state and get it back online after finish.

### 1) Used Methods

```
 // fullPath : the path for your database
 // executablePath : the path for your exe folder

    void setFullPath()
    {
        string executable = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        executablePath = (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(executable));
        fullPath = executablePath + "\\Database.mdf";
    }

    void takeOffline(string fullPath)
    {
        homeObject.connection.Open();
        homeObject.cmd.CommandText = "ALTER DATABASE [" + fullPath + "] SET OFFLINE";
        homeObject.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        homeObject.cmd.Clone();
    }

    void bringOnline(string fullPath)
    {
        homeObject.cmd.CommandText = "ALTER DATABASE [" + fullPath + "] SET ONLINE"; ;
        homeObject.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        homeObject.cmd.Clone();
        homeObject.connection.Close();
    }
```

### 2) Copy database files / Backup

```
  bool getDatabaseCopy()
    {
        try
        {
            //
            takeOffline(fullPath);

            // copy database.mdf
            copyDBMDF();

            // copy database_log.ldf
            copyDB_logLDF();

            //
            bringOnline(fullPath);

            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            //
        }

        return false;
    }

    // txtPath.txt :
    // folder location to save database files in

    void copyDBMDF()
    {
        string fileName = "Database.mdf";

        string sourceFile = fullPath;
        string targetPath = txtPath.Text;

        // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.
        string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

        // To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
        // Create a new target folder, if necessary.
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
        }

        // To copy a file to another location and 
        // overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
    }

    void copyDB_logLDF()
    {
        string fileName = "Database_log.ldf";

        string sourcePath = executablePath;
        string targetPath = txtPath.Text;

        // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.
        string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
        string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

        // To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
        // Create a new target folder, if necessary.
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
        }

        // To copy a file to another location and 
        // overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
    }
```

### 3) Replace current database files with files you copy / Restore

```
  bool restoreTheBackup()
    {
        try
        {
            //
            takeOffline(fullPath);

            // load .mdf
            loadMDFDatabaseFile();

            // load _log.ldf
            loadLDFDatabaseFile();

            //
            bringOnline(fullPath);

            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            //
        }

        return false;
    }

// txtPath.txt :
// location to get database files from to replace with current files.

    void loadLDFDatabaseFile()
    {
        string fileName = "Database_log.ldf";

        string targetPath = executablePath;
        string sourcePath = txtPath.Text;

        // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.
        string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
        string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

        // To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
        // Create a new target folder, if necessary.
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
        }

        // To copy a file to another location and 
        // overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
    }

    void loadMDFDatabaseFile()
    {
        string fileName = "Database.mdf";

        string targetPath = executablePath;
        string sourcePath = txtPath.Text;

        // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.
        string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
        string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

        // To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
        // Create a new target folder, if necessary.
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
        }

        // To copy a file to another location and 
        // overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
    }
```