# Restoring Database using LDF and MDF file (no .Bak)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My scenario would be,

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

I have a database deployed in our test environment and have populated it with my sample data, BUT I have been writing my stored procedures here also. I did this because I don't want to mess with the production data whilst I am testing my codes. Then yesterday, my superior accidentally restored the database to a later version, thus, I have lost a total of 6 months worth of work with that restore, could I still restore the database from a point in time? specifically August 14?

What I have tried:

I tried to use ApexSQL Log, but I cant seem to get any good result, I used the redo / undo function of this tool. Both option did not restored the database (maybe because I am using a trial version perhaps?)

That's just it since I don't have any backups on my test database (which I think I should have)

EDIT: I should point out too that the recovery model of that test Database is selected in "SIMPLE"

Edit: I am Still trying to check any utility which is free, to help me with this trouble. I just recreated my deleted database.

Comment: [Here you go mate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309677/restoring-database-from-mdf-and-ldf-files-of-sql-server-2008)

Comment: @Nobody, I did that and have attached the database already to my local machine. The problem is, the data is already selected to the most recent change that have occurred, which is the past data restored by my superior.

Comment: I'm confused. So you have written a bunch of sprocs in a database. That database is overwritten by a new database, causing loss of work. Is that correct? So do you have the other database as MDF/LDF? It sounds like you have nothing at all... Don't you have version control?

Comment: You got it right. Sadly we have just 2 database for that matter one is the test database and another for production, we do have version control on our backups on our production database, but none in our test database.

Comment: In that case I'm afraid you'll just have to do the work again. Make sure to use version control this time :P

Comment: @HoneyBadger Arent the SQL logs suppose to have the changes made by the database? If there really is no way for me to restore my data, I'll be doing everything from scratch.

Comment: It depends on how the database was replaced. If it was an actual restore, the logs only contain information from the new database, not the one it replaced. You could try some of redgate's software. You could also ask a question on database.stackexchange. Make sure the new question explicitly states you want to retrieve information from a replaced database. This question didn't make that clear. Good luck, hope you find a solution!

Comment: @JasonClark yah, all for $999

Comment: Yes, The software is capable to restore the database from ldf file only.