# Updating old db

Tags: sql-server

I am taking back a project that is not mine (web site) and I have to update the db. Problem is that there is no  gui and the one who create the whole thing doesn't remember much. (It is a mysql db and it is on windows server r2 2012)

I found this folder which seems contain the db (sherlockCOM).

[image]

So do you anyway (with cli or gui) allowing me to make my updates?

Comment: Those are SQLSERVER files,are you saying you need to update db named sherlockcom,if this is the case, you can search for a tool named `ssms` you can't directly update those files, you need to first restore them if you haven't..I recommend try following a tutorial first  and know basics

Comment: yeah that s what I should have used (this was the tool that was installed on the develop version but on the server it wasn't installed) but when I try to install it, I have to make a windows update (which server doesn't let me do, but I will try to contact my vm guy). But when you say restore them, you mean once I have sims, restore them on it?

Comment: not sure what you are trying to say,ssms now is seperate installer, you can download it and also check out this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309677/restoring-database-from-mdf-and-ldf-files-of-sql-server-2008

Comment: great thx a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restoring database from .mdf and .ldf files of SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309677/restoring-database-from-mdf-and-ldf-files-of-sql-server-2008)