# How to copy SQL Server file to transfer data

Tags: sql-server, copy

I have a Windows server with SQL Server installed on it. However the disk boot sector is bad and the windows server cannot boot. This disk is still readable from another computer. I have data in SQL Server which I did not make any backup.

Is there a way to save the data from the old SQL Server and transfer it to a new SQL Server I am going to setup? Is there a file I can simply copy over from the old disk to the new disk?

Thanks you so much in advance.

Comment: You may be able to take the .mdf and .ldf files and reattach them to a new instance of SQL. If you created your databases in the default folders, it would be something like `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\.....`.

Comment: Hopefully part of your plan is to create a recovery plan. Not taking backups is a bad start to recovering data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restoring database from .mdf and .ldf files of SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309677/restoring-database-from-mdf-and-ldf-files-of-sql-server-2008)