# Rationale for SQL Server to have database under Program Files

Tags: sql-server

From [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21877630/1016065) I learned how to attach a database, i.e. a set of `mdf/ldf` files, to SQL Server.

Basically you have to put the files in a specific location, `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\`

What is the rationale for this? How can you change it an why should or shouldn't you do this?

Surely this is not a big deal at all for small databases, but for large ones, is this good practice?

Comment: The location for database files is customizable in SQL Server setup. All practical production setups change this location to something else (usually a separate drive); it's a default because SQL Server's own installation directory is the only place it can be sure of. It could hardly decide to pick (say) `D:` by default, since it doesn't know if that's available on the target system.

Comment: *"Basically you have to put the files in a specific location,"* not at all, you can put the files wherever you want, *provided* that the service account that SQL Server is running under has access to that path. When you install SQL Server, the account is only going to have access to where it was installed; that's just good minimalistic permissions standards. If you want to move your databases, or create them elsewhere, that's fine and up to you; you just need to set the permissions of the service account first before you can.

Comment: @Larnu, thanks, but just to clarify:  _put files in specific location_, is the most upvoted answer to the question I referred to. That's what got me wondering in the first place.